# why is my stat_summary function not working in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar graph with grouping by a certain category, however I keep getting this error message

```
Computation failed in `stat_summary()`
Caused by error in `call_f()`:
! Can't convert `fun`, a double vector, to a function.
```

This was my code, which I hoped would create a bar graph grouped by gender

```
ggplot(aes(x=ses,y=weigh,group=gender,),data = datagraph)+
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = 'bar', position = position_dodge())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you wanted?

```
datagraph <- tibble(
  ses = factor(sample(c('c', 'd'), 100, T)),
  weigh= c(rnorm(50), rnorm(50, 0.5)),
  gender = factor(c(rep('a', 50), rep('b', 50)))
)
ggplot(aes(x=ses,y=weigh,group=gender, fill = gender),data = datagraph)+
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = 'bar', position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: When I tried that I got the same error message :/

Comment: Sorry, I read the help page for stat_summary again. I don't find that super clear either. I wonder if quoting mean like in the edited response produce something you wanted?